# Using Graph API to restrict access to the web application website to only specific users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an azure web application which is accessible by all the users of our organization.
In a .Net what are the possible ways to restrict access to certain set of users of a web application. MFA is already there, but still I need to restrict it to a specific group of users.

Please let me know how can I proceed further on this using Graph API in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the tags it sounds like you are using Azure AD authentication.

In that case you can go to Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise applications.
Find your application in the list and open it.
Then you can go to Properties tab and set *User assignment required?* to *Yes*.

Then open the Users and groups tab and assign the users you want to be able to access the app.

Comment: I have tried this method but still other users whom I didn't assigned were also able to access my website

Comment: And you set User assignment required to Yes? I've used this approach successfully at least so it should work.

Comment: Yes, did set User assignment required to Yes

Comment: Is there anything additionally to be done besides this steps ?

Comment: Hello @Nishant-MSFTIdentity yes still looking for any help

Comment: @Rupali Please follow the steps mention in the following document and let us know if the issue persists ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users#:~:text=Select%20the%20application%20you%20want,and%20set%20it%20to%20Yes.)

Comment: Is there any way I can achieve it using MS Graph API. I have edited my question as well.